# jQuery DataTables page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a quick question with Data tables.

Whenever I load the page, I noticed that non formatted version of the site loads and then the formatted version of the site.

I'm using the jQuery DataTable plugin, but it seems that every time I reload the page, it shows the jQuery not being implemented but in a few seconds later, I see that the page is formatted correctly.

How can I have the jQuery DataTable load every time a person refreshes the page?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I also used JQuery Datatables. is it flicker? 
If So, It seems that it is bug on library itself. If not, check your css setting. I think you should resize a table as your data's length.

Comment: The library was installed before I started working on the page. It came from http://datatables.net/. Here is the script that is calling the DataTable:$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#example').dataTable({
    stateSave: true,
"aoColumnDefs": [{ 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [ 4,5,6,7 ] }],
"lengthMenu": [[1, 5, 10, 15, -1], [1, 5, 10, 15, "All"]]
});
});